# Radio button show/hide content

Tags: css, radio-button, show-hide

I am trying to achieve a show/hide result without javascript and just the radio button.

I've managed to get to this part:

```
<label for="show"><span>show</span></label>
<input type=radio id="show" name="group">
<label for="hide"><span>hide</span></label>    
<input type=radio id="hide" name="group">
<span id="content">Content</span>


input {
    display:none;
}

span#content {
    display:none;
}
input#show:checked ~ span#content {
  display:block;
}

input#hide:checked ~ span#content {
    display:none;
}
```

Demo:
http://jsfiddle.net/vtfqW/

What I am trying to do now is to hide each time the "Show" and "Hide" buttons when they are active. So it will need to start with hidden content and just has the "Show" button and when you click it show the content, hide the "Show" button and show you the "Hide" button.

Is this possible without Javascript?

Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Place label tags after both in the input tags. Like below

```
<input type=radio id="show" name="group">
<input checked type=radio id="hide" name="group">
<label id="id1" for="show"><span id="id1">show</span></label>
<label id="id2" for="hide"><span id="id2">hide</span></label> 
<span id="content">Content</span>
```

Add these css rules to existing rules

```
input#show:checked ~ label#id1{
  display:none;
}
input#show:checked ~ label#id2{
   display:block;
}

input#hide:checked ~ label#id2{
   display:none;
}
input#hide:checked ~ label#id1{
   display:block;
}
```

demo http://jsfiddle.net/vtfqW/1/

Comment: Although it looks good, does it load by showing everything or is it just me?

Comment: Made 1 tiny change and it now works awesomely! Thank you very much!

Comment: it loads by showing everything. If you just want "show" to be displayed initially, add "checked" attribute to hide radio input.

Comment: Thanks for this useful solution. However in my case I need the radio `<input>`s to be inside a `<fieldset>`, and for some reason the CSS doesn't work anymore. Any ideas why, and how to make it work also if the `<input>`s are in a `<fieldset>`?

Comment: Update: I found out that it works if the span is inside the fieldset too, but not outside. Any way to make it work outside too? Cf. [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sc28/vtfqW/348/)

Answer (score 0):

If you want make content toggle. Menu toggle example.

```css
input#toogle-content {
  display:none;
}
label#toogle-content div{
   background:silver;
}
span#content {
  display:none;
  background:#333;
  color:#fff;
}
input#toogle-content:checked ~ span#content{
  display:block;
}
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" id="toogle-content">
<label for="toogle-content" id="toogle-content"><div>Menu</div></label>
<span id="content">Home<br>Marks<br>Other</span>
```