# Toggle display of HTML "spinner" input

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-ui, spinner

I found a way to toggle visibility of `span` or `input` elements using CSS, based on whether a radio-box is checked (inspired by this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21269376/radio-button-show-hide-content)).

However, I lose this toggling effect as soon as I apply a jQueryUI spinner format.

This [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sc28/vtfqW/351/) shows how the CSS works fine for the `span` element, but not for the `input`. In fact, as soon as I apply the spinner, the entire `input` disappears.

Any clues why this is happening, and how to toggle its visibility using CSS?

Here's the CSS i'm using in the fiddle:

```
    /* Control visibility of SPAN and INPUT (with jqueryui spinner class)
cf. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21269376/radio-button-show-hide-content
*/

/*The span works fine*/
span#some-text {
    display:none;
}
input#on-input:checked ~ span#some-text{
  display:inline;
}
input#systematic-input:checked ~ span#some-text{
  display:none;
}

/*The input is only visible when the spinner format isn't applied (i.e. commenting all CSS below this point). Even so, the hide/show effect doesn't work. Why?*/

/*
input#spinner-on {
    display:none;
}
input#on-input:checked ~ input#spinner-on{
  display:inline;
}
input#off-input:checked ~ input#spinner-on{
  display:none;
}
*/
```

Comment: But this works . . . http://jsfiddle.net/47zw914j/

Comment: @hex it works, but only because the jQueryUI "spinner" formatting isn't applied anymore. I was looking for a working solution where the spinner was activated, as proposed by AlkaRocks below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

jQueryUI spinner wraps the input in a span element.

Wrap the spinner input in a new span, specified by you, and apply CSS accordingly.

```
span#spinnerWrapper {
     display:none;
}
input#on-input:checked ~ span#spinnerWrapper{
  display:inline;
}
input#off-input:checked ~ span#spinnerWrapper{
  display:none;
}
```

Check this jsFiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/scc0jyns/2/

Comment: Great, many thanks: simple and effective. I didn't think of wrapping it in a span, which makes it even more convenient as I can wrap both the spinner and the side text in the same span, simplifying the overall CSS.